# 'Syntax Error' when returning True on Python 3.2

Tags: python, function, return

I have the following function in my script at the minute:

```
def _convert_time(p):
    """Converts a percentage into a date,
    based on current date."""

    # This is the number of years that we subtract from
    # the current date.
    p_year = pow(math.e, (20.344 * pow(p, 3) + 3)) - pow(math.e, 3)

    # Returns in YYYY-MM-DD format
    date_in_history = date.today() - timedelta(days=(p_year * 365)

    # Return to the control loop
    return True
```

All of my functions use this system of returning True at the end, this is due to there being a central function which runs each function in sequence and check if they ran correctly before executing the next function.

However, when I run the script, before I even get to input a value to start the script, I get the following error:

```
 File "C:\Users\Callum\Desktop\Tempus\TempusTest.py", line 59
 return True
      ^
```

If I make a function in the IDLE that returns True and check it, it works fine, but for some reason it doesn't in my script

Have you guys got any ideas on why this might be?

Thanks! :)

Comment: If there's no value returned (or at least, it is not contingent on anything), I recommend you scrap the system of returning True, and stick to 'return'.  If some unexpected behavior occurs, I think it is better to instead raise an error. In other words, True is always returned if it doesn't error out from the above two assignments, so True is ... not meaningful. But if an error occurs it goes unhandled and halts.  Especially since you're doing a check on the returned 'true', its also stylistically against Python virtue of 'act first, apologize later' (assume values will work, and catch if bad)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are missing a bracket.

You need to change this line:

```
date_in_history = date.today() - timedelta(days=(p_year * 365)
```

with:

```
date_in_history = date.today() - timedelta(days=(p_year * 365))
                                                              ^
                                                              |
                                                       it was this one :)
```

**Q: Why was it showing an error on the return line and not there?**

Because the error is actually there.

How could Python know that you weren't going to give another legit `timedelta` argument on the next line?
Or adding a `+100` to `(p_year * 365)`? *(like DSM suggested)*

Let's take a look at this IDE session:

```
>>> t = ('one', 'two',
...      'three'
... def f(): pass
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    def f(): pass
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The IDE couldn't know that my tuple was finished and I wasn't going to add a `'fourth'` element.

You may want to play the devil's advocate and say that I dind't typed the comma so Python should have guessed that I was going to end the tuple there.

But take a look at this other example:

```
>>> t = ('one', 'two',
...      'three'
...      'fourth')
>>> 
>>> t
('one', 'two', 'threefourth')
```

So as you see the error occured exactly when Python encountered a `return True` in a place where it wasn't supposed to be.

Comment: Thank you! :D So why was it showing an error on the return line and not there?

Comment: @CallumBooth: because the next line could have been something like `+ 100` or something.  You don't need to close a parenthesis on the same line, so it only *became* a syntax error at the return.  In general, when you have a SyntaxError in a line which looks fine, it's usually because of an unterminated element before it.

Comment: @Callum: DSM already explained that for me, anyway I've improved my answer.

Comment: @ DSM @Rik Poggi: Thank you, I just got a bit confused as to why it was occurring there, thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

The error is on the line before.

```
date_in_history = date.today() - timedelta(days=(p_year * 365)
                            10            1     2            1

date_in_history = date.today() - timedelta(days=(p_year * 365))
                            10            1     2            10
```

Missing a close paren

Comment: To elaborate on this answer: Python can't tell you where you made the mistake, it can only tell you where it got confused. Since Python automatically continues the statement on the next line if parentheses are open, it only gets confused when it sees `return` in (what it thinks is still) the middle of an expression.

Comment: @kindall: vocabulary failure. Python is not confused; it is correctly detecting and reporting a syntax error at the first possible token.

Comment: I'm anthropomorphizing. I know computers hate that, but I can't help it.